# BE_HTTP_GET_File returning text

Tags: function, get, ftp, filemaker

I am trying to pull a csv file into my FM15 database from FTP using BE_HTTP_GET_File.

By using the BE_CurlTrace at the end of the script, I can see that connection to the FTP is always successful, however instead of grabbing the file and returning it to a container field or documents path (I have tried both unsuccessfully) the BE_CurlTrace output simply lists all the text in the file within the BE_CurlTrace output :/

Am I doing something wrong, I know my syntax is correct on the BE_HTTP_GET_File as I have used this before, and I'm also getting a successful connection, I just can't seem to get the actual file into a container or local filepath.

Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks

[image: edit -Please see code attached]

Comment: Looks like you have an incomplete sentence in your question and you should also include a code example.

Comment: HI Andreas, apologies, I have edited and included code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the BE_HTTP_GET function directly in the Set Field line. Don’t use the trace function like that, it’s for debugging.

Comment: On the Set Field step, would I set the target field as a container? And export it out the container? I can't seem to get this to work, the result in the container is '?'

Comment: Yes, use the set field on a container field. You should get your ftp file as a result.

Comment: For some reason, it does not work into a container using the set field method. I am left with a '?' in the container field, the only way I can get this to work successfully is if I set it like so
BE_HTTP_GET_File ( "ftp:/ftpaddy/filename.csv" ;  "filename.csv" ; "username" ; "password" )

Using the set up above in a set field step places the file on my desktop. But I really could do with this going to documents or a container field, if I use the Get (DocumentsPath) & "filename.csv" this is unsuccessful. Very frustrating.

Comment: Use the BE_HTTP_GET function for container storage. In my answer I copied the function name from your post and overlooked that you were using the BE_HTTP_GET_FILE function. This is the correct format: `BE_HTTP_GET ( "ftp://server/path/file.txt" ; "thefile.txt" ; <user_name> ; <password> )`. I have updated my answer.

Comment: God bless you, Andreas, that has done it! I was so close yet so far away! Thankyou for your continued help and patience.